# How to get Windows Activation status on all PCs in a specific OU in Active Directory using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, admin

I am trying to scan computers in a specific OU in my AD to get the activation status of Windows.

I keep getting
`Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'CN=PCNAME,OU=MY-OU' failed: No such host is known`

although when i try to test the command against a single remote PC, it works fine getting the output

I tries getting all hosts using

`$Hosts = Get-ADComputer -Filter \* -SearchBase "OU=MY-OU"`

and then ran a for loop to test the connection of each host and using

```
foreach ($PC in $Hosts) {
    if (Test-Connection $PC -Count 1) {
    $License = Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" -ComputerName $PC |where { $_.PartialProductKey } | select Description, LicenseStatus

    $csv =          [PSCustomObject]@{
                    License      = $License 
                    Computername = $PC
                }
            

        }
    }
Write-Output $csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your $PC value is like this
$PC = "CN=server1,OU=OU1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=domain,DC=org"
in order to get computer name, split the string like below and use that value for test-connection
$CN = $PC.Split(',')[0].Split('=')[1]

```
$domainName = "CN=server1,OU=OU1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=domain,DC=org"
$CN = $domainName.Split(',')[0].Split('=')[1]
$CN
```

**Edited:** There are multiple properties in $Hosts, so instead of splitting distinguished name, use Select-object to get dns hostname.
I do not have an environment to test this code.. so please try yourself.

```
$Hosts = Get-ADComputer -Filter \* -SearchBase "OU=MY-OU" | Select-Object dnsHostName
$csv = foreach ($dnsHostName in $Hosts) {
    Write-Output $dnsHostName
    if (Test-Connection $dnsHostName -Count 1) {
        $License = Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" -ComputerName $dnsHostName | where { $_.PartialProductKey } | select Description, LicenseStatus

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            License      = $License 
            Computername = $dnsHostName
        }
    }
}
$csv | Export-csv -Path C:\temp\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: i added `$PC = $Hosts.Split(',')[0].Split('=')[1]` after getting the get -Adcomputer but im still getting the same error

Comment: Also when i try changing the code a little bit, im now getting error `Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer] does not contain a method named 'Split'.`

Comment: Using Select-object to get the hostname worked! Thanks!